# SASS, вложение дочернего правила в родительское

Tags: css, gulp, sass

html, описывает несколько кнопок:

```
<div id="button" class="one"><h1>кнопка номер раз</h1></div>
```

Через препроцессор для группы с общим id "button" задаю некоторые общие стили, затем, чтобы задать некоторые индивидуальные свойства - обращаюсь по классу:

```
#button
    background-color: #000
    .one
        background-color: #024b9d
```

Увы, фон всё еще черный... Читал статьи с похожими проблемами, вроде я все делаю верно (это конечно не так): отступы во всем файле одинаковые (через таб), расширение у файла sass, остальные свойства работают да и gulp не ругается...

Comment: В приведенном вами sass стили будут компилироваться так: `#button { background-color: #000; } #button .one { background-color: #024b9d; }` (то есть у вас `.one` является не классом `#button`, а его дочерним элементом), используйте амперсанд, что бы указать предшествующие селекторы: `&.one`

Comment: спасибо большое!